# How to access a class from a bundle of lower version?

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I have two OSGi bundle with same name. But there versions are different. Suppose one bundle has version 1.0 and another one is 2.0 . as 2.0 is higher version so its priroty will be first. But I want to use a piece of code from bundle 1.0 also. How can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

The bundle version is not reall important when OSGi selects where to import a package from. The only limitation there is that you can not install two bundles with the same symbolic name and version.

What you need is to version the packages the bundles export. Each of the packages can be exported with a different version if you want. In the client bundle you can then import each needed package with an allowed version range.

So bundle 1.0 can export package a in version 1.0 and package b in version 1.1.
Bundle 2.0 can export package a in version 2.0 and package b in version 1.2.

In the client bundle you could then

- import package a with a version range of [1.0,2.0) -> would resolve to package a from bundle 2.0
- import package b with a version range of [1.1,1.2) -> would resolve to package b from bundle 1.0

You can only do this on the package level though. So you can not access classes that are in the same package from different bundles - at least not without fiddling with classloader... which you should avoid.